# Json string values in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have following JSON string in a global variable in Javascript

```
var domains = {
    "DomID00001": {
        "ID":"DomID00001",
        "Name":"Testdomein1"
    },
    "DomID00002": {
        "ID":"DomID00002",
        "Name":"Testdomein2"
    }
};
```

What is the best way to retrieve the values from this JSON string and be able to use them in  Javascript individually?

If I just alert the domains var it says = [object Object]

Comment: That's not a JSON string, it's a JavaScript object. You access it like any other JavaScript object.

Comment: Objects cannot be alerted.  So console it, like `console.log(domains)`

Comment: There is no JSON in your example anywhere in sight. At first I rejoiced - somebody said JSON *string* - but then you have an object. Usually people make the opposite mistake, they have a string and claim it to be an object... oh and I edited your example, because if you write it like I did you can see its structure **much** better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the keys are variable, you should probably use a `for..in` loop:

```
for( domid in domains) if( domains.hasOwnProperty(domid)) {
    console.log(domid,domains[domid].ID,domains[domid].Name);
}
```

Comment: I used this approach in order to retrieve the values. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7):

Using `alert()` will not show you objects, this is one of the big advantages of the console. Check [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/P7MGz/) and use the console (pressing F12 on your browser). Then you understand how to refer to what is inside that object.

```
var domains = {"DomID00001":{"ID":"DomID00001","Name":"Testdomein1"},"DomID00002":{"ID":"DomID00002","Name":"Testdomein2"}};

console.log(domains);
console.log(domains.DomID00001);
console.log(domains.DomID00001.ID);
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see how this answers the question... Maybe I'm just misunderstanding the question... or your answer... =_=

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, I think both your (which I upvoted alone apparently) and my answer give some light into how to retrieve data from the object. Now we both have to wait if OP already knew about object property /values and if some questions still are unanswered.

Comment: Also interesting, much gratitude for the help. I looked into this and indeed gave some insight on how to do things. But after all I went with the Dark Absols solution below. Still upvotes this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var domains = {"DomID00001":{"ID":"DomID00001","Name":"Testdomein1"},"DomID00002":{"ID":"DomID00002","Name":"Testdomein2"}};

var strName1 = domains.DomID00001.Name;
var ID1 = domains.DomID00001.ID;
alert('Name: ' + strName1 + ' - ID: ' + ID1);
```

Comment: Works but too static for what I need. This into a for loop and perfecto ;D still +1 thanks!

Comment: I don't think for .. in is good about speed, you know! Just try something like JSON.parse(), stringify() ...etc. Thank you for voteup